# Typelist of nested types

Tags: c++, template-meta-programming, typelist

I've got a typelist providing the following interface :

```
 template <typename... Ts>
    struct type_list
    {
        static constexpr size_t length = sizeof...(Ts);

        template <typename T>
        using push_front = type_list<T, Ts...>;


        template <typename T>
        using push_back = type_list<Ts..., T>;
        
        // hidden implementation of complex "methods"

        template <uint64_t index>
        using at;

        struct pop_front;

        template <typename U>
        using concat;

        template <uint64_t index>
        struct split;

        template <uint64_t index, typename T>
        using insert;

        template <uint64_t index>
        using remove;
    };
```

In another piece of code, I have such a typelist `TL` of types statically inheriting a base class providing such an interface :

```
template<typename Derived>
struct Expression {
   using type1 = typename Derived::_type1;
   using type2 = typename Derived::_type2;
};

struct Exp1 : Expression<Exp1> {
    template<typename> friend struct Expression;
    private:
    using _type1 = float;
    using _type2 = int;
};

struct Exp2 : Expression<Exp2> {
    template<typename> friend struct Expression;
    private:
    using _type1 = double;
    using _type2 = short;
};
```

I want to make the typelist of nested types from `TL`, something like :

```
using TL = type_list<Exp1, Exp2>;
using TL2 = type_list<TL::type1...>; // type_list<float, double>
```

but I can't expand TL as it's not an unexpanded parameter pack.

I've thought about index_sequence but can't manage to make it work.

Comment: `template <typename T> using push_front;` etc.? That doesn't make any sense. You made your [mre] *too* minimal.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude indeed, but is it necessary to include 400 lines of implementation ?

Comment: how are we supposed to help when all the implementation is missing?

Comment: a [mcve] is not **all** the code. It is a short example with enough code to reproduce the issue

Comment: This also feels very much like an [XY problem](https://xyproblem.info/). You show us your (incomplete) solution to a problem that we know nothing about. What is the original problem you need to solve? Perhaps there are other solutions possible?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude updated. Hope it's clearer now

Comment: your `type_list` has no `type1`. I don't understand how `using TL2 = type_list<TL::type1...>;` is supposed to work. Please try to create a complete [mcve]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question is seemingly looking for `map`, also called `transform` in C++. `TL` is one list of types, and the desire is to apply some type-level function (extract ::type1) and have another list of types. Writing transform is straightforward:

```
template <template <typename> typename fn, typename TL>
struct type_list_transform_impl;

template <template <typename> typename fn, typename... Ts>
struct type_list_transform_impl<fn, type_list<Ts...>>
{
  using type = type_list<fn<Ts>...>;
};

template <template <typename> typename fn, typename TL>
using type_list_transform = type_list_transform_impl<fn, TL>::type;
```

And then the type-level function:

```
template <typename T>
using type1_of = typename T::type1;
```

And combine the pieces to get TL2:

```
using TL2 = type_list_transform<type1_of, TL>; // type_list<float, double>
```

Example: https://godbolt.org/z/b7TMoac5c

Comment: Wonderful. It was way easier than I though.